# PHP parse a CSV file - should it be stored in the database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a php/mysql application, part of which allows the user to upload a csv file. The steps in the process are as follows:

1. User uploads a file, and it gets parsed to check for validity
2. If the file is valid, the parsed information is displayed, along with options for the user to match columns from the csv file to database columns
3. Import the data - final stage where the csv data is actually imported into the database

So, the problem that I have at this point is that the same csv file gets parsed in each of the above 3 steps - so that means 3 parses for each import.

Given that there can be up to 500 rows per csv file, then this doesn't strike me as particularly efficient.

Should I rather temporarily store the imported information in a database table after step 1? If so, I would obviously run clear up routines to keep the table as clean as possible. The one downside is that the csv imports can contain between 2 and 10 columns - so I'd have to make a database table of at least 11 columns (with an ID field)...which would be somewhat redundant in most cases.

Or should I just stick with the csv parsing? Up to 500 rows is quite small...

Or perhaps there is another better alternative?

Comment: Why not just one step: Upload and put into database?

Comment: @ulvund Cant upload and put it straight into the database. As mentioned, the user has to match columns from the csv file (which can be in any order) with database columns.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, you can store data into the Session memory for later use. This allows you to parse the CSV file only once, save it in the Session memory and use this object in all of the later steps.

See http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php for a small tutorial.

Let me explain a bit more.
Every time a web browser requests a page from the server, PHP executes the PHP script associated with the web page. It then sends the output to the user. This is inherently stateless: the user requests something, you give something back -> end of transaction.

Sometimes, you may want to remember something you calculated in your PHP script and use it the next time the page is requested. This is **stateful**, you want to save state across different web requests.

One way is to save this result in the database or in a flat file. You could even add an identifier for the currently connected user, so you use a per-user file or save the current user in your database.

You could also use a hidden form and save all of the data as hidden input fields. When the user presses "Next", the hidden input fields are sent back to the PHP script.

This is all very clumsy. There is a better way: session memory. This is a piece of memory that you can access, which is saved across different PHP calls. It is perfect for saving temporary state information like this. The session memory can be indexed per application user.

Please note that there are frameworks that take this a lot further. Java SEAM has an APPLICATION memory, a SESSION memory, a CONVERSATION memory, a PAGE memory and even a single EVENT memory.

Comment: I already make extensive use of sessions in my app. In fact, sessions are encrypted and stored in the database for security. So, it would be round-tripping the database anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just stick with parsing it 3 times. PHP is slow anyways, as are the network latencies for using the database or sending information to the client. What's most important is that your code is **maintainable** and **extensible**. The slowest part of a computer program is the developer.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize

http://ubiquity.acm.org/article.cfm?id=1147993

http://benchmarksgame.alioth.debian.org/u32/which-programs-are-fastest.html

Hope that helps...

Comment: "PHP doesn't get good results for this benchmark on this hardware" != "PHP is slow"

Comment: It's the same hardware (and problem) for all languages. That's why they call it a benchmark. Yes, PHP is slow; but I still use it because it's fast to program in. If you want something to RUN fast, write it in C or C++.

Comment: My point is that the benchmark doesn't necessarily reflect how any real application will perform since the application probably won't perform the same tasks as the benchmark. Although it probably is a reasonable estimate.

Comment: You're right. Different problems must be benchmarked for the specific problem they're solving. However, this benchmark is exactly that. Each of the submissions are solutions to the same problem. And, as you can see, depending on how some people implemented the solution, they were able to get quite close to 1.00. So, the skill of the implementer is a large factor too. I'm not trying to discourage optimization, only to put PHP optimizations into the larger context of all instructions that run through the CPU.

Comment: Yes, I understand that each implementation of the benchmark is solving the same problem. But this assumes that a solution to ANY problem will have the same relative performance as the benchmark, which is not necessarily the case. That is, one language may be more efficient for a particular type of problem.

Comment: There are 14 different benchmarks on that page and the numbers represent all of those results. However, the first two sections of this page http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/dont-jump-to-conclusions.php#jump discuss some of the points that we've been discussing a bit further. Cheers and thx for the thought exercise. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a similar thing for importing users into a database. What I ended up doing was this:

- Import and parse CSV
- Assign data to an array
- Next page had a bunch of hidden form fields each with the data (ex. `<input type="hidden" name="data[]" value="thedata" />`)
- Post it over and add the data to the database

It ended up working well for me. You can also save the data to session variables.

Comment: This is almost equivalent to resubmitting the data at each step of the process and seems rather wasteful.

Comment: Look at the last sentence in the answer.

Comment: Missed that. But the primary recommendation still seems to be resubmission.